Different nginx config file for each environment
I am trying to load a different nginx config file for each environment I have, the reason is that for dev I am using certbot in a single instance, and I need to load the SSL certificates and open port 443, but on prod I have the certificates in the "certificates manager" and I also use a load balancer. I would like to deploy different nginx configs depending on the environment, how can I do that?
This is my current config
events {}

http {
    server {

        
        listen      80;
        listen 443 default ssl;
        server_name ~^(.+)$;

        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;

        # force https-redirects
        if ($scheme = http) {
            return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
        }

         # root directive should be global
        root /var/www/html/webroot;
        index index.html index.php;


        ssl_certificate      /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key  /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem;

       
        access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log   /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        proxy_read_timeout 300;
        proxy_connect_timeout 300;
        proxy_send_timeout 300;

        location / {
            try_files $uri \$uri /index.php?$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/php-fpm/www.sock;
            fastcgi_index   index.php;
            fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
        }

    }

}

I would like to add aconditional like if($ENV_NAME = prod) .... But I tried and even ENV_NAME is an environment variable, I got this error :
unknown directive "if($ENV_NAME" in /var/proxy/prod/nginx/nginx.conf:10 

Thanks
